# How to go back to Original Position after hover on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, rotation, hover

i have a Picture in HTML and i rotate it on hover.

On PC it works. It rotates and if i leave the image it rolls back. On iOS Hover does not work for me correct.

If i tab the Picture it Rotates but it does not Rotate back to its Original state.

Is there a way that it returns 0 after amount of Time? (Tried that but was not Working)

I tried with `onClick` and a few other things but i did not find any way to rotate it back.

I noticed that if on the Page is another hover effect on iOS and there is another tab on the second one the first goes back to normal.

```
<header>
<img src="images/Logo1.png" alt="Logo" class="profile-image">
</header>

header .profile-image:hover, .profile-image:active {
  transform: scale(2.3) rotate(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed seting `scale` and `rotate` to initial values?

```css
.profile-image {
    /* animation duration on transform */
    transition: transform .2s;

    /* set initial values */
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}

.profile-image:hover,
.profile-image:active {
    transform: scale(2.3) rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img width="50px" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/04/19/beach-1867285_960_720.jpg" alt="Logo" class="profile-image">
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for you Answer mate. But it does not work on My iPhone X. I tried with my Page and i tried with your Code Only.

Answer (score 0):

try with `-webkit`

```
.profile-image {
    /* animation duration on transform */
    transition: transform .2s;

    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);

    }
    header .profile-image:hover, .profile-image:active {
      transform: scale(2.3) rotate(360deg);
      -webkit-transform: scale(2.3) rotate(360deg);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer as well but it is still not going back to its Original Form and Size.